# I need to compare multi arrays and log out the differences in JavaScript.This is a nested array of any possible length

Tags: javascript

This is what I have, currently, I am able to get the difference. But as you will see from the arrays I am comparing I want to return 2 values. That is if I compare the First array in a1 with the first array in a2, I should get the difference, likewise, if I compare the Second array in a1 with the second in a2, I should get the difference which is 4.Right now I am only getting one value back.

```js
var findDivergence = function (a1, a2) {

  for (let q = 0; q < a1.length; q++) {
    var result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a1[q].length; i++) {
      if (a1[q][i] !== a2[q][i]) {
        result.push(i);
        console.log(result.length)
      }
    }
  }
  return `Length is : ${result.length}`;

};

console.log(findDivergence([
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], 
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
  ], 
  [
    ["a", "b", "d", "r", "e", "q", "g"], 
    ["a", "2", "d", "r", "e", "q", "g"]
  ]
));
```

Comment: please add the result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood well you need main variable ( desiredResult) for accumulated differences form nested arrays.

```js
    var findDivergence = function (a1, a2) {
 var desiredResult = [];
  for (let q = 0; q < a1.length; q++) {
    var result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a1[q].length; i++) {
      if (a1[q][i] !== a2[q][i]) {
        result.push(i);
        console.log(result.length)
      }
    } desiredResult.push(result);
  }
  return desiredResult;

};

console.log(findDivergence([["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]], [["a", "b", "d", "r", "e", "q", "g"], ["a", "2", "d", "r", "e", "q", "g"]]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does exactly what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
var zip = function(a1, a2) {
  const len = a1.length < a2.length ? a2.length : a1.length;
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result.push([a1[i], a2[i]]);
  }
  return result;
}

var findDivergence = function (a1, a2) {
  const result = [];
  for (const [aa, bb] of zip(a1, a2)) {
    let divergences = 0;
    for (const [a, b] of zip(aa, bb)) {
      if (a !== b) divergences++;
    }
    result.push(`Length is ${divergences}`);
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(findDivergence([["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]], [["a", "b", "d", "r", "e", "q", "g"], ["a", "2", "d", "r", "e", "q", "g"]]));
```

Comment: Thanks, it was what I wanted. I think I was mutuating the result variable initially after each iteration.